# fragment shader and glDrawArrays

Tags: opengl, glsl

is it possible to use fragment shader to set one color channel of a rendering and

```
glColorPointer(...);
glDrawArray();
```

to set the 2 others colors channels.
If yes how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are stepping to the programmable pipeline then I also suggest stepping away from `glColorPointer` `glVertexPointer` and the matrix stack and instead use `glVertexAttribPointer` and pass the transformation matrices as uniforms.

In the fragment shader you would do

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(channel1, channels2_3.xy, 1);
```

Where channel1 and channel2_3 can come from either a uniform or a attribute passed from the vertex shader.

Comment: I'm new to openGl your explanation is little bit tricky for me, does it mean i should write a vertexshader ? should I still use glDrawArrays? glDrawArrays() will still work fine if I use glVertexAttributePointer(...) instead of glVertexPointer(..)?

Comment: You'd have to create the vertex shader anyway. `glDrawArrays` will still work fine.

Comment: Don't you need to declare the output variable explicitely? I think `gl_FragColor` is a reserved name that can't be used.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that depends on the version openGL 3.3 would use gl_FracColor while 4.x needs explicit declaration (IIRC)